# How to know which loss function is suitable for image classification?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, loss-function

I am implementing a CNN model for image classification where I am learning about loss functions. There are several types of loss functions to determine error. However, how do we find out which function is suitable for a image multi-classification model?

Answer (score 4):

If you have two classes (i.e. binary classification), you should use a binary crossentropy loss.

If you have more than two you should use a categorical crossentropy loss.

Answer (score 0):

For image classification in keras, with multiple categories, `categorical_crossentropy` is a good start.